# Angular 2 trigger event

Tags: javascript, events, output, angular, emit

I am trying to trigger a click event on another element but it doesn't work.

My Component:

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'generate-car',
  template: `
    <button [disabled]="!pressed" (click)="parkingCar()"  type="button"  class="parking">Parking Car</button>
    <car *ngFor="#car of cars" [class]="car.type" (animate)="test()">
        <span class="car-number">{{car.id}}</span>
    </car>
`
})
```

When I click on the button I need to trigger (animate) event.

My class:

```
export class GenerateCar {

@Output() animate = new EventEmitter();

parkingCar() {
    this.animate.emit(null)
}

test() {
    console.log( 111 )
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I think set up is not correct or something.

You need to understand the concept of `EventEmitter` of Angular2. It allows you to fire `custom event` of `DOM element` and propagate it to its parent.

I don't understand what you would like to do with `EventEmitter` with your example. But I'd like to give you a direction which might help you in your example.

***EventEmitter very simple example***

***boot.ts***

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
directives:[Car], 
template: `
    <div>{{name}} from parent</div><br>
    <car (animate)="test($event)"></car><bR>
        `
, 
})

export class BodyContent {  //ParentComponent

    name:string='Angular1';

      test(arg) {
          console.log('test start');
          //this.animate.subscribe((value) => { this.name = value; });
          this.name=arg;
          console.log(arg);
        }
    }
,
})
```

***car.ts***

```
export class Car {
      @Output() animate: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

      setValue()
      {
        console.log('setValue strat');
        this.animate.next('angular2');

        // You can also write below line in place of above line
        //this.animate.emit('Angular2');
      }
}
```

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4rwWSHQxBkLyxiXoe74A?p=preview)

---

***Note:***
***`(animate) = "test($event)`***: It will tell Angular to invoke the ParentComponent's `test($event)` method when `ChildComponent(car)` fires `animate`. The data that we passed to the “next()” method in `car`is available in `ParentComponent` by passing `$event` as an argument to the `test()` method.

For further information you can refer to [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-components-inputs-outputs/) nice article.

Hope this will help you to go further.